# Compare Two Strings With Wildcards

Tags: c#, regex

I need to compare two strings, one of which uses '*' as a wildcard. I was thinking of using either an iterative or recursive method when I realized that RegEx would perform the task more quickly. Unfortunately, I am new to RegEx, and am not sure how to do this.

If I sent in the pattern "He**o", then "Hello" and "He7(o" should return true, but "Hhllo" should return false.

Comment: Use `He..o` .The dot means any character

Comment: Please check if [this code](http://ideone.com/1ZwkkE) is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean `*` to be a single-character wildcard, the correct substitution in a Regex pattern is a dot (`.`):

```
string pattern = "He**o";
string regexPattern = pattern.Replace("*",".");

Regex.IsMatch("Hello",regexPattern); // true
Regex.IsMatch("He7)o",regexPattern); // true
Regex.IsMatch("he7)o",regexPattern); // false
Regex.IsMatch("he7)o",regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // true
```

You might also want to anchor the pattern with `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string):

```
regexPattern = String.Format("^{0}$", pattern.Replace("*","."));
```

If you expect it to be able to parse input strings with special characters, you'll can escape all other characters like this:

```
string regexPattern = String.Join(".",pattern.Split("*".ToCharArray())
                                             .Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare the strings by using the char index in a for loop. If the pattern char (wildcard) appears, ignore the comparison and move on to the next comparison.

```
private bool Compare(string pattern, string compare)
{
    if (pattern.Length != compare.Length)
        //strings don't match
        return false;

    for(int x = 0, x < pattern.Length, x++)
    {
        if (pattern[x] != '*')
        {
            if (pattern[x] != compare[x])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Regex using "He..lo"

This is a case that will not be recognized

```
Regex r = new Regex("He..o");
string test = "Hhleo";
bool sucess = r.Match(a).Success;
```

This is a case that will be recognized

```
Regex r = new Regex("He..o");
string test = "He7)o";
bool sucess = r.Match(a).Success;
```

Comment: I forgot to enter an "e" in the regex, try again now, already edited my post

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I've done in `php` today. When you add this:

```
if (pattern[x] != '*' && compare[x] != '*')
```

Then both strings can have wildcards. (hope that `&&` means logical AND like in `php`)