# Implement wildcard search

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Any thoughts how to add a wildcard search from the line similar to sql 'like%'. in my case to get the result, exact search gives the result. I need result's which match or like based on the searchkey

```
List = (from x in employee 
        where x.firstname.ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.ToUpper()) 
        || x.fullname.ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.ToUpper())  
        select x)
        .Take(5);
```

Comment: There is no in-built function for this, so far I know, so you will have to implement it yourself eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130564/string-comparison-with-wildcard-search-in-c-sharp | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299671/matching-strings-with-wildcard | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112162/compare-two-strings-with-wildcards

Comment: Is `employees` a DbContext, or a local collection?

Comment: @Neil why is it matter?

Comment: @snr - if code can be translated to SQL or not

Comment: Because if `employee` is a DbSet (i.e. it's a database query), then using `.Contains` will be translated into a SQL Like automatically, and there is no need to use `.ToUpper` because case insensitive search is the default.

Comment: @Neil - `case insensitive search is the default` is it really? for all databases (mysql, ms sql, sqlite...), for all cultures (en-us, de-de, fr-fr....)?

Comment: @Neil yes its a dbcontext. in my case e.g full name is john a. bravo, when someone search for john bravo. there are no search result

Comment: Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410864/10646316) it handles small variation of wildcards but it will work with EF. Extending  should be simple.

Comment: @RandRandom Unless you have changed it, the default collation for MySql and MsSql are case insensitive.

Comment: @RandRandom ISO SQL requires a case-insensitive default collation for Latin text - and (AFAIK) _every_ even-barely-ISO-SQL-compliant RDBMS around today also defaults to case-insensitive collation. I've never come across an RDBMS that defaults to case-sensitive collation for Latin text.

Comment: To be clear, LINQ to DB implements `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains` using a translation to SQL `LIKE`, adding `%` as appropriate, but you can't add additional wildcards yourself. However, depending on your EF version and database (what are they?) you can use something like `EF.Functions.Like(x.fullname, $"%{searchKey.Replace(' '. '%')}%")`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have changed the default collation (sorting/searching), it is very likely that SQL will do a case insensitive search by default.   Using `string.Contains` will automatically be converted into LIKE %xxx%.

```
List = (from x in employee 
    where x.firstname.Contains(searchKey) 
    || x.fullname.Contains(searchKey)  
    select x)
    .Take(5);
```

`string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith` will also be converted to `LIKE "%XXX"` and `LIKE "XXX%"` respectively.

Comment: Of course, the problem with the `LIKE %` operator it isn't SARGable. The main way to have _fast_ substring queries is with a suffix-trie, but those are a PITA to build in an RDBMS - it's often much easier just to fall-back on the RDBMS' built-in full-text indexing feature, if available.